# ruby socket dgram example

Tags: ruby, sockets, unix-socket

I'm trying to use unix sockets and SOCK_DGRAM in ruby, but am having a really hard time figuring out how to do it.  So far, I've been trying things like this:

```
sock_path = 'test.socket'
s1 = Socket.new(Socket::AF_UNIX, Socket::SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
s1.bind(Socket.pack_sockaddr_un(sock_path))

s2 = Socket.new(Socket::AF_UNIX, Socket::SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
s2.bind(Socket.pack_sockaddr_un(sock_path))

s1.send("HELLO")
s2.recv(5) # should equal "HELLO"
```

Does anybody have experience with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In common case you need use `connect` and `bind` for both client and server sockets, so you need two different address for binding

```
require 'socket'

sock_path = 'test.socket'
sock_path2 = 'test2.socket'

s1 = Socket.new(Socket::AF_UNIX, Socket::SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
s1.bind(Socket.pack_sockaddr_un(sock_path))

s2 = Socket.new(Socket::AF_UNIX, Socket::SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
s2.bind(Socket.pack_sockaddr_un(sock_path2))
s2.connect(Socket.pack_sockaddr_un(sock_path))

s1.connect(Socket.pack_sockaddr_un(sock_path2))
s1.send("HELLO", 0)
puts s2.recv(5)

=> HELLO
```